# Angular Directive's template binding doesn't update

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive set up here http://jsfiddle.net/screenm0nkey/8Cw4z/3 which has two bindings to the same scope property, but for some reason the binding in the directive's template property doesn't update when the model changes (after typing in the input).

```
<test>
    <h3>Inner {{count}}</h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="count">
</test>

var App = angular.module('App', []);
App.directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: "<h1>Outer{{count}} <div ng-transclude></div></h1>",
      controller: function ($scope) {
        $scope.count = 1;
      }
    };
  });
```

But if I move the input position in the markup it works and both bindings update.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="count">
<test>
     <h3>Inner {{count}}</h3>
</test>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/screenm0nkey/dCvZk/3

Can anyone explain why the position of the input containing the binding, would have an affect the bindings. I assumed that during the digest loop the watchers for both binding would be updated regardless of the position of the markup.

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To me, this seems purely to be a scope issue.  Lets take a look at the markup that is generated by both:

**Not working:**

```
<body ng-app="App" class="ng-scope">
  <h1 class="ng-binding">Outer1 <div ng-transclude="">
    <h3 class="ng-scope ng-binding">Inner 1</h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="count" class="ng-scope ng-pristine ng-valid">
    </div>
  </h1>
</body>
```

**Working:**

```
<body ng-app="App" class="ng-scope">
  <input type="text" ng-model="count" class="ng-valid ng-dirty">
  <h1 class="ng-binding">Outer <div ng-transclude="">
    <h3 class="ng-scope ng-binding">Inner </h3>
    </div>
  </h1>
</body>
```

The `ng-scope` class is a useful marker for where Angular is declaring a new scope.

You can see by the markup that the in the working example both the `count` properties are enclosed in the `scope` that is attached to `body`.  So, in this case, the `directive` scope is a child of the `body` scope (and therefore has access to it).

However, In the example that is not working, the `Outer1` property is sitting outside of the scope that the `input` is in.

The [Angular Scope documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope) covers this well.  The scopes are arranged in a hierarchy with child scopes having access to parent scopes (but not the other way around):

> The application can have multiple scopes, because some directives
>   create new child scopes (refer to directive documentation to see which
>   directives create new scopes). When new scopes are created, they are
>   added as children of their parent scope. This creates a tree structure
>   which parallels the DOM where they're attached

[image: angular scope heirarchy]

Comment: Mind if I ask - what tool did you use to generate the "scope" image? Looks very nice! :)

Comment: This is an image link directly to the Angular docs. :) http://docs.angularjs.org/img/guide/concepts-scope.png

Comment: I bloody get it now and that's all down to your answer, good sir. Well, yours and that egghead video:) So in the 'working' version the input is updating the parent scope, so they both update but in the 'not working' version the input is updating the child scope, but as it's adding a literal property to the scope, that cloaks the property on the parent, which is why using an object works.

Answer (score 2):

Long story short - as others have said, this is a scope issue. Using the "ng-transclude" directive creates a new scope. When a new scope is created *values* from the old scope will be accessible in the new scope (hence the first replace) but after that only objects that are shared between the old/new scope will be updated. That is why using an object would work, but using a value will not.

In your case placing the input field inside of the ng-transclude causes this to only edit the value in that scope, not the value in the parent scope (which is where the count for the "test" directive is pulled from).

Incidentally, this can be an issue with repeaters (ng-repeat) as well as other directives. Its best to use a tool such as "[Batarang](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-batarang/ighdmehidhipcmcojjgiloacoafjmpfk?hl=en)" in order to find issues such as this. It allows you to look at what is in each scope and determine why the screen isn't showing the "correct" data. Hope that helps explain further!

Comment: Values are not copied.

Comment: @zeroflagL I believe you & can update, but why is it that you can access *values* in children scopes that were set in a parent scope? It seems that there is a "one-way" copy of sorts that allows these values to be inherited if they haven't been set in the child. Maybe you can drop a link that could explain!

Comment: It works because of prototypal inheritance. I eventually decided to give my own answer to explain the technical details a little bit.

Answer (score 1):

Here's [a work around](http://jsfiddle.net/roine/8Cw4z/4/)

Change `$scope.count` to

```
$scope.helper = {
    count: 1
}
```

and refactor the rest.

[Check this video out](https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot) for an explanation.

Comment: Hi Jonathan, that does indeed work. I'm not trying to fix anything. I just wanted to know why it didn't work. Can you tell me why it works with nested properties on the scope but not with properties directly on the $scope. also can you tell me why moving the input also works. Many thanks

Comment: Did you check the video, it might answer your question.

Comment: The video link wasn't there when i replied but I will take a look. Many, many thanks:)

Answer (score 1):

The order matters because of the difference between creating a property on the scope versus actually using an object bound to the scope (especially when a transclude creates a new child scopr).  Best practice is to use an object on the scope and bind properties to that object when scope issues can come into play with directives and transcludes.

If you change your code to this, it will work as you were expecting and order does not matter.  Notice that I am creating a scope object and placing the count as a property on that object.

```
<test>
    <h3>Inner {{data.count}}</h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="data.count"/>
</test>
```

---

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.directive('test', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      replace: true,
      transclude: true,
      template: "<h1>Outer{{data.count}} <div ng-transclude></div></h1>",
      controller: function ($scope) {
          $scope.data = {};
          $scope.data.count = 1;
      }
    };
  });
```

This is a great tutorial on this subject.  Props to EggHead. https://egghead.io/lessons/angularjs-the-dot

Answer (score 1):

Add `ng-change` to `input` , it should work. The problem is that controller into directive doesn't know about `count` change.

**JS**

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.directive('test', function () {        
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        replace: true,
        transclude: true,
        template: "<h1>Outer {{this.count}} <div ng-transclude></div></h1>",
        controller: function ($scope) {
            $scope.count = 1;

            $scope.onChange = function(count){          
              $scope.count = count;          
            }
        }       
    };
});
```

**HTML**

```
<test>
     <h3>Inner {{count}}</h3>
    <input type="text" ng-model="count" ng-change="onChange(count)">        
</test>
```

Demo <kbd>**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8Cw4z/10/)**</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

It's a scoping issue.

`$scope.count = 1;` adds the property `count` to the scope that `<test>` is in. Let's call it parent scope.

`ng-transclude` creates a new scope, let's call it child scope. When `<h3>Inner {{count}}</h3>` is evaluated, the child scope has no property `count` so it's read from the parent scope.

`<input type="text" ng-model="count">` binds the value of the input to the property `count` in the child scope. As soon as you enter something the property will be created if it's not there yet. From this point on `<h3>Inner {{count}}</h3>` gets its value from the child scope.

Scopes in angular are simple JavaScript objects and are connected to their parents via prototypes. So before you enter something the child scope looks something like

```
{
  prototype: { // = parent scope
     count: 1
  }
}
```

When you change the value to, say, 5, the scope looks something like

```
{
  count: 5,
  prototype: { // = parent scope
     count: 1
  }
}
```

Because data binding does something like `scope.count = 5`.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that we cannot override this since `ngTransclude` will use `$transclude` function directly.
See: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/src/ng/directive/ngTransclude.js

and: http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$compile

> transcludeFn - A transclude linking function pre-bound to the correct transclusion scope. The scope can be overridden by an optional first argument. This is the same as the $transclude parameter of directive controllers. function([scope], cloneLinkingFn).